# Adding a new column to a list of data frames and then 'unlist' with names intact?

Tags: r, loops, lapply, cbind

I have a number of dfs to which I want to add a column.
For the sake of a mrp, these dfs are called df_1, df_2, df_3...

```
for (i in 1:10) {
assign(paste("df_",i,sep = ""),data.frame(x = rep(1,10), y  = rep(2,10)))
}
```

I want to add another column z to each of these dfs.

```
z <- rep("hello",10)
```

How can I accomplish this?

Using lapply I have been able to do this

```
q <- list()
for (i in 1:10) {
q[[i]] <-  assign(paste("df_",i,sep = ""),data.frame(x = rep(1,10), y  = rep(2,10)))
}
z <- rep("hello",10)
q <- lapply(q, cbind,z)
```

This adds the required column, however, I don't know how to preserve the names. How can I still have df_1, df_2, etc but each with a new column z?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Using `` `[<-`() ``.

```
q <- lapply(q,`[<-`, 'z', value=rep("hello", 10))
```

Gives

```
str(q)
# List of 10
# $ :'data.frame':  10 obs. of  3 variables:
#  ..$ x: num [1:10] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#  ..$ y: num [1:10] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
#  ..$ z: chr [1:10] "hello" "hello" "hello" "hello" ...
# $ :'data.frame':  10 obs. of  3 variables:
#  ..$ x: num [1:10] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#  ..$ y: num [1:10] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
#  ..$ z: chr [1:10] "hello" "hello" "hello" "hello" ...
# ...
```

This works, because `` `[<-`(df_1, 'z', value=z) `` is similar to `df_1[['z']] <- z`. (Actually we're using `` base:::`[<-.data.frame()` ``.)

**Note:** You might get `q` a little cheaper using `replicate`:

```
n <- 3
q <- replicate(n, data.frame(x=rep(1, 3), y=rep(2, 3)), simplify=FALSE) |>
  setNames(paste0('df_', 1:n))
q
# $df_1
#   x y
# 1 1 2
# 2 1 2
# 3 1 2
# 
# $df_2
#   x y
# 1 1 2
# 2 1 2
# 3 1 2
# 
# $df_3
#   x y
# 1 1 2
# 2 1 2
# 3 1 2
```

Comment: Thanks, though I am afraid I do not understand how this works. Could you please shed some light?

Comment: @NiGS Done! Does this help?

Comment: Still doesn't work after the edit. 'res' is a list of 0 if code is run as it is. What does `mget(ls(pattern='^df'))` this do? And why can't I use `list2env` on the list q? :)

Big thanks again!

Comment: @NiGS `mget` looks for objects provided as strings, and `ls()` lists your environment, by default the `.GlobalEnv`, where we look for `pattern='^df'` where `^` stands for _beginning with_.

Comment: @NiGS Sure you may use `q` directly. See update. I just was confused because I initially used your first `for` loop. `mget` no longer needed:)

Comment: Thanks for all the explanations and edits :)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can slightly adjust your own list-method such that the names of the data frames are also stored:

```
q <- list()
for (i in 1:10) {
  q[[paste0('df_', i)]] <-  data.frame(x = rep(1,10), y  = rep(2,10))
}
z <- rep("hello",10)
q <- lapply(q, cbind,z)
```

Edit: using `list2env` mentioned by @jay.sf, the dfs are returned to the global environment.

```
list2env(q , .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! Using the `list2env` function provided by @jay.sf , I can get the dfs back to the global environment.

Answer (score 0):

Functionally the same as @jay.sf's answer, slightly more verbose/more lines of code, but perhaps easier to understand using `transform()`.

```r
# create dataframes
for (i in 1:10) {
  assign(paste("df_",i,sep = ""),data.frame(x = rep(1,10), y  = rep(2,10)))
}

# store dataframes into a list (only objects starting with df_)
df_list <- mget(ls(pattern="^df_"))

# add new column to each dataframe
lapply(df_list, \(x) transform(x, z = rep("hello", 10)))
```